# Cannot resolve symbol error even tho everything works fine (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, classpath

Okay, It's driving me nuts. I tried everything and can't solve this. So here's the problem:
When I have messageSource cofigured like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

Everything is fine, but when I change to ReloadableBundleMessageSource, it doesn't find my 'messages' bundle for some reason, so I had to add classpath, like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

Now it works BUT IntelliJ keeps screaming that there is an error even tho everything works fine. classpath:messages is highlighted and says cannot resolve symbol classpath:messages.
Please, end my misery.

Comment: Try creating a bug report on YouTrack. Or you could also try disabling this particular inspection (or at least lower its level to warning so that it's less obtrusive)

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I've just made a post in their official forums.

Comment: Peoplay say it's been reported for over a year now, yet they still didn't fix it so I wouldn't have any high hopes about that one :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's no fix for that so I just ended up disabling this inspection.
 Thanks to **Bohuslav** for suggestion.

Comment: Yes is is a bug.Here is the link https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122239

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
      p:basename="/resources/messages">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

Sikor, please use **p:basename="classpath:messages"**